# Add title name to list of ggplots from the names of dataframes in list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am producing a list of boxplots from a list of data frames as so:

```
Bps<-lapply(dflist, function(x){
  gg<-ggplot(x, aes(x= x, y= y, fill= x))+
   geom_boxplot(position  = "dodge")+
    ggtitle(names(x))    
 })
```

The list of dataframes can be generated by:

```
 df1<-data.frame(x=seq(1:50), y=rep("Blank", "Non_blank",25))
 df2<-data.frame(x=seq(1:40), y=rep("Blank", "Non_blank",20))
 df3<-data.frame(x=seq(1:30), y=rep("Blank", "Non_blank",15))

dflist<-list(df1,df2,df3
```

I need to paste the names of the original dataframes as the title for each boxplot. So if dflist has 3 dataframes called dfA, dfB and dfC, these should be the titles of each boxplot made from the lapply function. I can only seem to get the name of a column and not the original dataframe name. 
Many thanks,
M

Comment: can you share the contents of `dflist` to make your question reproducible?

Comment: Please see edit, thanks

Comment: We could put all data.frames into one with Group column, and use `facet_grid`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the group column would still have to be the name of the dataframe, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is a sequential problem and we don't need to assign the outcome, we can use a `for loop`:

```
names(dflist) <- c("dfA", "dfB", "dfC") # Define names of df's

for (i in seq(dflist)) {
  gg <- ggplot(dflist[[i]], aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x))+
    geom_boxplot(position  = "dodge") +
    ggtitle(names(dflist[i]))
  print(gg)
}
```

Comment: This works in this instance however, I would like to automate this without having to define names(dflist) as the names of the dataframes will sometimes change. Thanks.

Comment: @MRF in your example the df's have no name at all, which is why I defined them.

Comment: Hmm, the names show up in the dflist as $'dfA' etc. Is there a way to extract this from the list and pass it to names(dflist)?

Comment: You don't need to define the names, if they are already present in your actual list of `data.frame`'s. But again, this is not the case for the example data you posted.

Comment: Sorry mtoto! I have managed to get it to work with your code, the names of the dflist was defined! It works perfectly thank you